# C++ | Anonymous namespace colliding with namespace std

Tags: c++

```
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

namespace {
   class priority_queue;
}

priority_queue pq;
```

How can I distinguish between the two priority_queue names? I tried `::priority_queue` to get the global one but to no avail.

Comment: How about not `using namespace std;`?

Comment: There are reasons why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice. You found one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Don't use an anonymous namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, just change

```
using namespace std;
```

to

```
//using namespace std;
```

Now you have to type `std::priority_queue` for the standard one and `priority_queue` or `::priority_queue` for the custom one.